# Access the ID of where results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to find the ID for a wostatuses table where the statuscode = 'INPRG'

I'm trying this, but I don't know how to extract the ID from the results:

```
      <%= inprogress = Wostatus.where(statuscode = "INPRG") %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to put it in your controller but if you need to access it in your views you can use

```
<% inprogress = Wostatus.where(statuscode = "INPRG") %>
 <%= inprogress.id %>
```

but these will return an array ,,you can use

```
  <%= inprogress.first .id %>
```

to get access to first one 
or you can use

```
<% inprogress.each do |inprogres|
 <%=inprogres.id %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: `where` is going to return an array; you need to at least add on `.first` to get an id off the model.

Comment: This worked:          <% inprogress = Wostatus.where("statuscode = 'INPRG'") %>
      <%= inprogress.first.id %>

Answer (score 1):

This code belongs in the controller.

Set an instance variable like,

`@inprogress = Wostatus.where(:statuscode => "INPRG")`

and in your view do this,

```
<%= @inprogress.map &:id %>
```